# fputc in c language write the wrong data to file when meeting the chars "d5dc"

Tags: c

> i want to convert text file to binary.
>
> for example:
>
> "0100ed73 ed000032 0100d5dc d5dc0012"
>
> every eight char need be converted to a int. part of my program is:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    start = tmp+i*9;
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        unsigned char a = ctoi(start[0+j*2])*16+ctoi(start[1+j*2]);
        fputc(a,outFilePtr);            
    }

}
unsigned int ctoi(char in)
{
    if(in>='0'&&in<='9')
    {
        return in -'0';
    }
    else
    {
        return in - 'a' + 10;
    }
}
```

> at most time it is right.but after the program convert the char
>   "d5dc",the out file no more match the in file.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is it the first or second sequence `d5dc` that causes trouble?  Have you printed each character as you call `ctoi()` so you know exactly what it's converting?  What debugging have you done?  How could we tell from what you've told us? (Hint: we couldn't!)

Comment: What is the output you expect given the input 'd5dc'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all。
Jonathan Leffler answer gives me inspiration。
i used notepad++ to check my result before。
the content of source file like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2dx7.png)

and the output file like this(use HEX-Editor plugin):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNDBe.png)
your can find they are not same.

when i see Jonathan Leffler answer,i decide to write a program to check the result,i found it is right.
so it is the bug of nodepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a minimal set of code around the code shown in the question, and adding diagnostic printing, produces an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned int ctoi(char in);

int main(void)
{
    char tmp[] = "0100ed73 ed000032 0100d5dc d5dc0012";
    FILE *outFilePtr = stdout;
    fprintf(stderr, "Hex data: [%s]\n", tmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        char *start = tmp + i * 9;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            unsigned char a = ctoi(start[0 + j * 2]) * 16 + ctoi(start[1 + j * 2]);
            fputc(a, outFilePtr);
            fprintf(stderr, "0x%c%c = 0x%.2X = '%c'\n", start[0 + j * 2], start[1 + j * 2], a, a);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

static unsigned int ctoi(char in)
{
    if (in >= '0' && in <= '9')
    {
        return in - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        return in - 'a' + 10;
    }
}
```

And, when run with the output run through a program that translates non-printing characters into `\xXX` hex escape sequences, the output is:

```
Hex data: [0100ed73 ed000032 0100d5dc d5dc0012]
0x01 = 0x01 = '\x01'
0x00 = 0x00 = '\x00'
0xed = 0xED = '\xED'
0x73 = 0x73 = 's'
0xed = 0xED = '\xED'
0x00 = 0x00 = '\x00'
0x00 = 0x00 = '\x00'
0x32 = 0x32 = '2'
0x01 = 0x01 = '\x01'
0x00 = 0x00 = '\x00'
0xd5 = 0xD5 = '\xD5'
0xdc = 0xDC = '\xDC'
0xd5 = 0xD5 = '\xD5'
0xdc = 0xDC = '\xDC'
0x00 = 0x00 = '\x00'
0x12 = 0x12 = '\x12'
\x01\x00\xEDs\xED\x00\x002\x01\x00\xD5\xDC\xD5\xDC\x00\x12
```

On the face of it, your code produces exactly the output it is supposed to produce, so it is not clear where you have a problem — except that it is probably not directly in the code shown in the question.